# ActionScript - Installing Documentation For Your Own Classes?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, documentation

Is it possible to write/install your own documentation for self-created classes along with Adobe's documentation in Adobe Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method of writing your own documentation for self-created classes would be ASDocs and if your going to go down that route, I would check out Grant Skinner's [ASDocr](http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/01/asdocr_simple_a.html) which is an air app to simplify the process of managed and writing ASDocs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure if you meant something other than ASDocs but check this out http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_1.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want documentation for your classes as the other suggested: you need to use ASdoc.

If you want to see the documentation you wrote for your classes inside the Flex Felp Pages... then this is **not possible**.

Comment: really?  that seems odd if it's true.  the docs from Adobe Help application (CS5) can now be optionally set to read offline documentation only (reading online docs is the default), so those libraries must be available somewhere on the computer, no?